# If simson line of P || AS prove that PA || BC

Tags: triangles, circles

**Question** -

If simson line of P with respect to ABC is parallel to AS , prove that PA || BC ...

**My try** -

I tried menelaus , similarity , angle chasing ...but none of them works ...I can write more thing which I have got but they are not working ...
Any hints ?

Thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure, let PA’ produced cut AS produced at T.

[image]

The Simpson’s line creates two circles (the red and the green).

z = x and x = y imply x = z. This further means T is another con-cyclic point of PABC.

Then, $\angle APT = 90^0$. Result follows.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you are trying to do...but if you are taking assumption that AS and PA' will meet on T which is on circumcircle then why yu did all this...it is obvious that angle in semi-circle will be 90° !!...

Comment: But the thing is how we know that AS and PA' will meet .. because in my diagram they are not meeting?? That's why I did not see it

Comment: And also if they meet ..then what is use of given condition that lines are parallel??

Comment: @User12002 PA' and AS will definitely meet at some point called T. But is T on the circle formed by P, A, B, C? To prove that it is so, I have to show x = z. If x is indeed equal to z, then, by the converse of angle in the same segment, T is a point on that circle. We can then say $\angle APT = 90^0$ because A(S)T is now the diameter.